# set width and height of text view dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

How can I set the width and height of a textview dynamically
I have already tried

```
displaytext.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(rlwidth-(rlwidth*5/100),rlheight-(rlheight*90/100)));
```

for which I have received this error

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

Comment: change LinearLayout.LayoutParams to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. It will work. because your textview inside RelativeLayout.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support, I got the answer for this. Its actually easier to set dimensions for a text view. This is the code I used.

```
displaytext.setWidth(rlwidth);
   displaytext.setHeight(rlheight*16/100);
   displaytext.setTextSize(rlheight*6/100);
```

Now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
displaytext.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(rlwidth-(rlwidth*5/100),rlheight-(rlheight*90/100)));
```

As per error logs, your `TextView` parent looks like `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "displaytext" for which you are dynamically setting the height nd width is of type relativelayout and you trying to cast into linearlayout.

```
        txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        txtview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#53565a"));
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams_txtview =(ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) .getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams_txtview.topMargin = 8*y/100;
        txtview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams_txtview);
        txtview.getLayoutParams().height = 4*y/100;
        txtview.getLayoutParams().width = 30 * x / 100;
        txtview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        txtview.setTypeface(typeface_regular);
```

U can use the code and modify according to ur requirements.